# How to access Django Test database to debug?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

Django tests are very helpful.
However, when it's time to debug it's more complicated.

I would like to:

- The test database does not disapear at the end of the tests suite to analyse it
- Be able to read in this database, using my graphical DB Manager (Navicat, pgAdmin, etc.) (which is more friendly than command line)

How to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [django-test-utils](https://github.com/ericholscher/django-test-utils) app includes a [Persistent Database Test Runner](https://django-test-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/keep_database_runner.html) to achieve this. I haven't tested the app myself though.